# Power Pivot: simple relationship between 2 tables

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

I am just getting started with Power Pivot.
I have 2 tables:

| EE_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Werner |
| 124 | Karl |

and

| SUP_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | Miriam |
| 521 | Jasmin |

actually those are related, so I created another table, which describes the relationship

| EE_ID | SUP_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 321 |
| 123 | 521 |

I connected them no in Power Pivot foreign key / primary key.
I thought I can run now a query which spits out

- Werner and than, somehow
- Miriam
- Jasmin

But I don't get to the list, where am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help!

Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined a relation ship in the right way then you only need to use the [related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax) function in the table which describes the relationship in order to populate one column with the superior's name and another one with the employee's name.

This is the view before defining these extra columns
[image]

Them you add two columns in tblRelation with
[image]

The table should then look like that
[image]

Now you only need to add a pivottable in compact format adding employee and superior to the rows

[image][image]

Result is

[image]